# Instantiating a base class inheriting from SKSpriteNode in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, sprite-kit, instantiation, skspritenode

I'm trying to write a generic `Alien` 'blueprint' class for my first iPhone game. This class will contain a handful of properties and methods that will be inherited by all the actual alien subclasses. That said, `Alien` really shouldn't have a texture and shouldn't have its own set of defined values.

```
    //Generic alien type: a blue-print of sorts
    class Alien:SKSpriteNode{

        let velocityVector:CGVector
        let startPos:CGPoint

        init(texture:SKTexture, startPosition startPos:CGPoint,moveSpeed: CGFloat,velocityVector:CGVector){
            super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

            self.velocityVector = normalizeVector(velocityVector)
            self.position = position
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
```

Every time I try setting this up I run into a handful of errors such as :

```
"Use of instance member 'normalizeVector' on type GameScene; did you mean to use a value of type GameScene instead?"
```

`normalizeVector` is a function that is written above the `Alien` class (within GameScene). I'm not sure what this means, as this is a normal function within the GameScene. If I remove this bit, I still receive the error:

```
"Property self.velocityVector is not initialized at super.init call"
```

I'm confused because I had thought that `super.init()` was only necessary because I'm making a subclass of SKSpriteNode and that it wouldn't need to have the subclass-specific properties passed to it.

Lastly, is there a way to call `super.init()` without having an actual texture as this blueprint class isn't ever going to be "displayed"?
After looking through Apples Documentation on classes/initialization I'm still stuck. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Why are you defining `Alien` within `GameScene`? A separate file would be more appropriate.

Comment: @appzYourLife I've done some research and haven't found much- should I be writing all the classes outside of GameScene? How about the game logic?

Comment: It's good practice writing different classes in different files. Please also read the [SpriteKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues, first of all, as the error message says, you need to initialize all variables before you call `super.init`:

```
init(texture:SKTexture, startPosition startPos:CGPoint,moveSpeed: CGFloat,velocityVector:CGVector){
    self.velocityVector = Alien.normalizeVector(velocityVector)
    self.startPos = startPos

    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

    self.position = position
}
```

Second, it sounds like you're defining `normalizeVector` in a subclass or somewhere else?  What I did was to define it as a static method (since it's used before this is initialized, it can't be an instance method) and then you can use it in the init method.  Put it all together and it looks like:

```
class Alien:SKSpriteNode {
    static func normalizeVector(vector:CGVector) -> CGVector {
        let len = sqrt(vector.dx * vector.dx + vector.dy * vector.dy)

        return CGVector(dx:vector.dx / len, dy:vector.dy / len)
    }

    let velocityVector:CGVector
    let startPos:CGPoint

    init(texture:SKTexture, startPosition startPos:CGPoint,moveSpeed: CGFloat,velocityVector:CGVector){
        self.velocityVector = Alien.normalizeVector(velocityVector)
        self.startPos = startPos

        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

        self.position = position
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: @ David Berry Thank you, that was very helpful. I'm still curious as to why I couldn't call a lone function inside the class. My function looked near identical to yours but it was placed directly above the class (inside GameScene). I received this error: `"Use of instance member 'normalizeVector' on type GameScene; did you mean to use a value of type GameScene instead?"` Also, why is `moveSpeed` not being initialized here?

Comment: `moveSpeed`'s not being used because, well, you don't use it for anything, perhaps you intended to create another `let moveSpeed : CGFloat` in which case you should initialize it before calling `super.init` as well.  As for `normalizeVector` if I pull it out of the class to the file level things still work as expected.  Perhaps you have it embedded in another class by accident?

Answer (score 0):

You declared `velocityVector` as a non optional property so of course if your don't populate it within your initializer you get a compiler error.

This is why when you comment this line your get a compile error.

```
self.velocityVector = normalizeVector(velocityVector)
```